# IOS share data between apps

Tags: ios, iphone-privateapi, data-sharing

Hi I want to share data/files between apps on the SAME IOS device.

The scenario: **one app pulls data** (from a server / up to 1GB) to the device, and **other apps should be able to access it**.

How can I achieve this?

- without a Jailbreak

Possible solutions:

- Just small chunks: keychain, clipboard, custom URL (actually how small /limited are they)

**If i don´t go for the appstore but direct B2B**

- what about private API and other things like this (as far as i am concerned the Apple   regulations do NOT apply to an in-house App Store)
- any other ideas?

thanks for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I could not give a full answer, but one of the option is the iCloud. If you set the same iCloud containers in your app's entitlements for each different apps, you can read/modified the shared files from your apps.It requires that both applications use the same Team ID.

"If you want to confer access to documents created by other apps published by your team, use additional strings to specify the bundle identifiers of those apps." More information [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/EntitlementKeyReference/Chapters/EnablingiCloud.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011195-CH2-SW1).

And it is an apple-friendly solution!

Comment: can u provide any link where there is more detail on this