# Getting path of plist stored in device

Tags: iphone

So, there is an app installed on the device. It contains a plist to store all the details. Is it possible to access that particular plist from another application? Where it will be residing? I found this code could be used for it!! Is it really possible? Or any other workaround to get it?

```
NSString *documentdir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
NSString *tileDirectory = [documentdir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@""];
NSLog(@"Tile Directory: %@", tileDirectory);
```

Even if I can find the path of that particular plist, would I be able to read it?

**EDIT:**

My Objective:

I have one app that uses plist to store data, this app uploads the data to a server.

Somehow this app failed to upload certain data available in the plist.

Now i need to get this data stored in the plist.

The app is not configured with iCloud,..

Any suggestions on how the data from the plist can be retrieved?

Comment: Is it possible to access that particular plist from another application? :NO

Comment: Is there any way around to do it..!!

Comment: if you failed to upload the data, why not schedule an upload for a later time? just try again when the user runs your app next time... keep "tasks" in a local sqlite or wherever you like.

Answer (score 1):

The code you provide will be locked to the application on a non-jailbroken device. It's indeed possible to list paths and find other applications' plists on a jailbroken phone.
General answer: No, it's not possible.

Comment: What if the application is developed by us and it is having some problem to post the data it has to the server.. Can we get the data it has from another app.

Comment: there are many ways to pass some data from one application to another. one of them is run a local webserver inside one app and access it via network from the other app (using localhost). you can also use custom copy/paste or url schemes to pass some data to other apps.

Comment: also here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11737209/ios-share-data-between-apps is a good idea how to use iCloud for this

Comment: there are many ways to pass some data from one application to another. one of them is run a local webserver inside one app and access it via network from the other app (using localhost). Means, both apps should use same domain??